# Can't mount .obb file (state = 21) on Meizu m3 note

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I've met with another strange issue with APK Expansion files (.obb-files). My expansion file mounts fine on all my test devices:

- Sony Xperia Z1 Compact (API 22)
- Sony Xperia Z1 Ultra (API 22)
- LG Nexus 5X (API 23)
- LG Nexus 4 (API 17)

I've created encrypted .obb file with *jobb*-utilite:

**jobb -o *obb-filename* -d *files-dir* -k *password* -pn *applicationId* -pv *versionCode***

In my app I read .obb file with following code:

```
public void initialize(final Context context) {
    final StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    final File mainObbFile = getMainObbFile();

    final OnObbStateChangeListener listener = new OnObbStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
            super.onObbStateChange(path, state);
            if (state == OnObbStateChangeListener.MOUNTED) {
                // work with obb file
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("OnObbStateChangeListener::onObbStateChange - can't mount .obb file (state = " + state + ").");
            }
        }
    };

    final String key = BuildConfig.MAIN_XAPK_KEY;
    if (storageManager.isObbMounted(mainObbFile.getAbsolutePath())) {
        // work with obb file
    } else if (!storageManager.mountObb(mainObbFile.getAbsolutePath(), key, listener)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't create listener for mounting .obb file.");
    }
}
```

And everything works fine. But on **Meizu m3 note** (API 22) we got strange error: "OnObbStateChangeListener::onObbStateChange - can't mount .obb file (state = 21)".

Previously, I have met with this problem and it was solved with another generation of .obb-file. But in this case it did not help. 
Also, I've tried to generate .obb file with *fixed* jobb tool (https://github.com/monkey0506/jobbifier.git), and it doesn't work.

May be anyone knows, what's wrong, why sometimes .obb files doesn't work on some devices?..

**UPDATE**
Also, I've checked mounting of non-encrypted .obb file on Meizu. It works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a quick check of file ownership (user AND group) and file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

> I had the same problem, and i figured out that many times Error 21 is
>   caused by Linux Files Permissions over the obb, and the problem is
>   that Android cannot have access to it so the StorageManager launches
>   Error 21. When you create the .obb file, change permissions and user
>   group to the file, something like:

```
$chmod 664 <obb-filename>.obb    
$chown user:group <obb-filename>.obb
```

Then try again, worked for me.

Comment: i gave access to "everyone", still same problem

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem with Error code `21` i removed the `-k password` from:

```
jobb -o obb-filename -d files-dir -pn applicationId -pv versionCode
```

and passed null in `mountObb` method instead password

```
storageManager.mountObb(mainObbFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, listener)
```

I don't know why `jobb` not work with password, if someone know please share.